# how to add a calendar to a conflicting meeting room

Tags: resources, google-calendar-api

This question regard of Google API(Calendar Resource).
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars/insert

When using the google calendar API, I did not know how to add a calendar to a conflicting meeting room that was reserved.
Normally calendars that are already in conflict at the time of adding will send an email to decline from the meeting room account. I want to register without declining.
Please tell me if anyone knows how to resolve with the resource API.

I want to execute the operation manually with the API at the following URL.
https://ithelp.brown.edu/kb/articles/control-how-your-resource-calendar-accepts-events

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding this parameter **`attendees[].responseStatus`** and setting it to **`accepted`**? See [**`Events: insert`**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) documentation.

Comment: thanks.I have already tried it. But, When the event is duplicated, an e-mail to decline is sent.